# How to give dropdown values based on check and uncheck of checkbox in angular2

Tags: angular

I have a checkbox based on selecting the checkbox, the values must be shown in the dropdown. But here, when i "unselect" both the checkboxes and again select both and "unselect" one, then the dropdown values remains same, it doesn't reset. Can anyone help me to sort out this?

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v8amqr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Ts:

```
 setFaxId(index: number, faxQue: any) {
        faxQue.isChecked = (faxQue.isChecked) ? false : true;
        let filteredArr = this.faxqueuelists.filter(x=>x.faxQueueID == faxQue.faxQueueID);
        if (faxQue.isChecked) {
            this._selectedFaxQueList.push(faxQue.faxQueueID);
            this.dropDownFaxQueueList.push(filteredArr[0]);
            if(this.dropDownFaxQueueList.length == 1){
                this.userGroup.get("DefaultFaxQueue").patchValue(faxQue.faxQueueID);
            }

        } else {
            this._selectedFaxQueList.splice(this._selectedFaxQueList.indexOf(faxQue.faxQueueID), 1);
            this.dropDownFaxQueueList.splice(this._selectedFaxQueList.indexOf(faxQue.faxQueueID),1);
            this.userGroup.get("DefaultFaxQueue").patchValue("");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace the `else` part by this:

```
let index = this._selectedFaxQueList.indexOf(faxQue.faxQueueID);
this._selectedFaxQueList.splice(index, 1);
this.dropDownFaxQueueList.splice(index,1);
```

The selected element is already deleted from `_selectedFaxQueList`, when doing the `indexOf()` second time (in your code), it won't give a proper result.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response, this is working for me, but here, the selected value is not setting as default on the dropdown input

Comment: i have 2 dropdowns, in that i had selected only one, after refresh, the input field is empty, it gives only the dropdown

Comment: It seems to be working fine for me. See the console, there is an error for the form. You may want to fix that before trying anything else.